# Call stack doesn't give a clue

Tags: c, stack, call, win64

We are having a 32Bit 'C' - Win32 Application that occasionally hangs

At the time of a Hang, (non Responsive state) the customer sent us the Dump 
When i opened the dump in Windbg, the call stack gives the following

```
wow64win!NtUserMessageCall+0xa
wow64win!whNT32NtUserMessageCallCB+0x32
wow64win!Wow64DoMessageThunk+0x8b
wow64win!whNtUserMessageCall+0x12e
wow64!Wow64SystemServiceEx+0xd7
wow64cpu!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x2d
wow64!RunCpuSimulation+0xa
wow64!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x42a
ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess+0x17e3
ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x28ff0
ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe
```

I am not getting a clue as the call stack is not pointing to our code.

PS :- 
The Hang situation is not just common for 64 bit systems.

Comment: That looks like the thread has send a message. Perhaps the process that owns the recipient window failed to respond.

Comment: The only other clue is that Our application is making a DDE connection with MS word and the Task Manager Screenshot shows both as non Responsive

Comment: What the lack of activity is telling you is that there is not enough information here to help you. You'll want to do some debugging. Gather information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need switch to 32 bits in windbg, `!wow64exts.sw`, this print out real stack trace for wow64 target.

Comment: Thank you so much. This did the trick :) I am now able to get the exact stack trace.